# Проблема при отправки данных с формы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! У меня произошла следующая проблема при отправки данных с формы он переадр. на обработчик и выдает белый экран все бы ни чего но ошибки я в коде не нашел он должен переадр. на новость обратно но увы....

```
add.php
    <?
include('/include/connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

if(isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
}

$date = date("d-m-Y â H:i:s");

if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
}

$text = addslashes($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$text = stripslashes($text);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $com_id = $id;
}

    $add_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (com_id,name,date,text)  values ('$com_id','$name','$date','$text')");

if($add_query == true) {
    echo "bad"; echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    windows.local = "otziv.php?id='$id'"
    </script>';
}

else {
echo "bad query";
}

?>
```

форма

```
print ' <form  method="post" action="include/add_com.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10" placeholder="Name" reqired>
        <input type="date" name="date" reqired><br> 
        <textarea type="text" name="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="text" required> </textarea><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="button">
        </form>'
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. В чем ошибка?

Comment: * Первая ваша ошибка - это то, что вы до сих пор используете устаревший вариант работы с БД (**mysql_***)
 * Вторая - то, что вы смешиваете php и js там, где это не нужно. Для переадресации достаточно средств php - [header()][1]
 * Что это такое и откуда оно берется?

        if(isset($_GET['id'])) { $id = (int)$_GET['id']; $com_id = $id; }

 * Поле **com_id** у вас с автоинкрементом? Если да, то зачем вы подставляете ему значение вручную. То значение, которое непонятно откуда берется (пункт выше)

 * Включите отображение всех ошибок.

   [1]:http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: в этих строках нет ошибки это 100% такой же код работает в другом месте и там нет белой стр. com_id это ид новости передается. где будет выводиться комент. (не автоинкримент) 
включал отображения белая стр.

Comment: ... Далее 

* Что за символ у вас затесался в этой строке?

        $date = date("d-m-Y â H:i:s");

* И если вы получаете дату в запросе, то зачем переопределяете её ниже?

        if(isset($_POST['date'])) { $date = $_POST['date']; }
        $date = date("d-m-Y â H:i:s");

* Запрос у вас POST, а переменную вы ловите, как GET:

        if(isset($_GET['id'])) { $id = (int)$_GET['id']; $com_id = $id; }


P.S. 
> в этих строках нет ошибки это 100%

Скажу по секрету, что весь этот код - это одна большая ошибка.

Comment: почему то да же phpinfo(); не выводит

Comment: это на потом она закоментирована #$date = date("d-m-Y â H:i:s");

Comment: спасибо, разобрался в чем проблема:) просто создал другой файл в него вставил код и good)

Comment: @Malyshev, это вам так кажется что good, а на самом деле - это не код, а "ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи". Вы даже не понимаете, что по сути в коде происходит. Взять к примеру две строки:

    $text = addslashes($text);
    $text = stripslashes($text);

В первой вы экранирует строку с помощью слэшей, а в следующей - сразу же удаляет экранирование символов. Где логика?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А файлы у Вас в одной директории находятся?
Форма отправляется к include/add_com.php, а редирект идёт к otziv.php, который по идее находится в директории выше.

Попробуйте такой редирект сделать.

```
header( 'Location: otziv.php?id='$id );
```

И вопрос: а запись в БД добавляется? Если Да то внимательней присмотритесь к конструкции

```
if($add_query == true)
```